# Xcode 7.1 hangs while archiving swift ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, archive

Xcode 7.1 while archiving app, hangs at 'Copying Swift standard libraries'.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For anyone else facing the same issue. After trying and failing everything else, it was fixed by restarting the mac :D

Comment: Hold `command` + `option` + `P` +`R` while rebooting, for added "just in case"-ness!

Comment: restarting or just a log out / log in helps, but why? I do not like to do that several times a day

Comment: Well. Today I had the same issue and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Log out, log back in.  Faster than restarting your mac!

Comment: has anybody found out why this helps? I do not like to log out and in several times a day

Answer (score 1):

If you are not planning to release on AppStore and only creating an ad hoc build for testing, then do the following:

In Xcode 7, Goto Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme From the left menu select "Archive" and Select "Distribution" from the "Build Configuration" drop down.

[image]

Comment: there is no distribution in xcode 6, only release, what to do?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the Wi-Fi connection. It seems that Xcode 8 tries to go out to the Internet for signing frameworks / apps and if that connection is really slow it takes a lot of time (for me up to 15 minutes). As soon as I changed the Wi-Fi network it built and ran in under 5 seconds.